# How report kernel module bug?

Tags: system

Thanks for using your free time reading my question.
I see happening an problem with dm-writeback in BTRFS when happen partial written damaging the file system in power failure.
Where report kernel module dm-writeback bugs ?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: I searched the web for "btrfs bug report", and the first hit [gave me this](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ): *Please report bugs on Bugzilla on kernel.org (requires registration) setting the component to Btrfs, and report bugs and issues to the mailing list (linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org; you are not required to subscribe).* So do that - and `btrfs` issues really aren't specific to Ubuntu, so I gather this topic will be closed.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Not close it.
I want report about kernel module dm-writeback.